# Mapstruct mapping one target To another target - java

Tags: java, mapstruct

```
Mapstruct version : 1.4
java - 8
```

I have a use case where i need to map target to target

```
//target
public  class Office {
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumberWithcode // some logic needs to do
    private String department;
    private String phone;
}

//my source - My Address string has phone Number
public  class Department {
    private String Address; # 
    private String empNumber;
    private String department;
}

    @Mappings({
       @Mapping(target = "phone", source = "Address", qualifierName="getPhoneFromAddress"),
    })
public abstract Office getOfficeFromDepartment(
    Department dept);
```

What I am trying to do

1.My Department doesnt have phone number attribute. phone is available only as part of `Address` string

2.Get phone from `Address` String

3.use that phone attribute  to create attribute `phoneNumberWithcode`

**Problem**

I want to map this extracted `phone` to `phoneNumberWithcode`

```
    @Mappings({
       @Mapping(target = "phone", target = "phoneWithCode", qualifierName="convertPhoneToPhoneWithCode"),
    })

public String convertPhoneToPhoneWithCode(){
//some processing
}
```

Error:
Duplicate Attribute target

Now both phone and PhoneWithCode is available only with target "Office"

How do I achieve this. Is it even possible with mapstruct. I am aware it can be achieved outside of mapstruct. Trying to see if is possible with mapstruct.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you can extract phoneWithCode from Address too.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Mapping` annotation is tailored towards mapping from one source to one target.

Since you have already found a way to do the mapping from `Adrress` to `phone` why not apply that twice?

e.g.

```
@Mapping(target = "phone", source = "Address", qualifierName="getPhoneFromAddress")
@Mapping(target = "phoneWithCode", source = "Address", qualifierName="getPhoneFromAddress")
public abstract Office getOfficeFromDepartment(
    Department dept);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to perform with @AfterMapping annotation:

```
@Mapping(target = "phone", source = "phone")
Office map(String phone);

@AfterMapping
default void update(@MappingTarget Office office) {
    String phone = office.getPhone();
    office.setPhoneWithCode(convertPhoneToPhoneWithCode(phone));
}
```